# Making class nil and releasing the reference

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

In my code I do,

```
ClassA *reference = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[reference invokeMethod];
reference = nil;
[reference release];
```

Without the reference = nil I know it releases the memory cos its normal way to do so. But in this situation if we make the reference nil and release the memory later does it remove the earlier memory consumed for object creation?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `release = nil` just makes the memory it originally points to unaccessible; it won't remove the memory consumed. (Also, this causes the `[reference release];` statement afterward a no-op.)

Answer (score 1):

As kenny said, Release = nil just makes the reference object point to nil. now you've lost control of the ClassA allocated object, and cant release it so a memory leak occurs. And [reference release] is trying to release memory of a nil object, so that would cause a crash aswell.